# Tables and view not visible in QGIS 3.10.2

Tags: qgis, geopackage, sql-view

Using QGIS 3.10.2 I created a geopackage DB with 2 geographic layers and some tables, later on I edited the same geopackage with the DB Browser for SQLite 3.12 and created a View, add another table and changed a name of one of the first tables ('Material' was changed to 'Poste_Material'). Later on, In QGIS again,  I re-connected to the geopackage and found that all what I had added/changed with the DB Browser is not visible, not the view not the tables. (I reconnected several times)

I have been looking in the internet and have not found at least the reason why the new table is not visible, neither if there is something wrong with the view.

The SQL I used to create the view is this (I borrowed the syntax from spatialite views):

```
CREATE VIEW 'CABLES' AS
SELECT C.Id_Cable, P.Nombre_Propietario, L.Id_Linea,  L.geometry as geometry
FROM LINEA AS L
LEFT JOIN CABLE AS C ON L.Id_Linea = C.Id_Linea
LEFT JOIN Propietario as P ON P.Id_Propietario = C.Id_Propietario
WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY L.Id_Linea, C.Id_Cable
```

[image: DB Manager from QGis]

[image: DB Browser for SQLite]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with geopackage, why not create a table instead of a view?

Comment: Thank you, I want to create views because the geographic layers are related to domain tables and the model is designed to capture the information like that from field work.